# TP4056 overheating when not charging

Tags: circuit-design, battery-charging, lithium-ion, tp4056

I am currently working on a project that involves charging 18650 Li-Ion battery through USB-C using TP4056. Nothing really fancy (or at least have I thought!).

The circuit is pretty simple - Battery connected permanently to the TP4056; the rest of the circuit (two boost converters, ESP32 etc.) is separated by toggle switch (SW3).

[image: Schematic of the charging circuit]

Now, very weird thing happens when the user tries powering on / off the rest of the device by toggling the switch - the TP4056 starts drawing approximately 1A **from the battery** and instantly overheats, even though **it is not plugged into the USB (+5VP rail is disconnected)**. This does not stop until I take out the battery.

This problem happens only from time to time, so it is pretty random. However one interesting thing is that when I tried to power the device with my lab PSU instead of the battery, it used to happen a lot more.

I managed to capture the moment, when I toggled the switch and the problem occurred. The screenshot shows voltage on pin 5 of the TP4056 when toggling the switch:

[image: Oscilloscope screenshot when toggling the switch]

but IMHO there is nothing *that* special, that should "lockout" the IC until it is reset.

The TP4056 that was causing me problems was ordered from LCSC, PN C16581. Then, I swapped it with another TP4056 (again from LCSC, but PN C382139), made by a different manufacturer and now it works flawlessly. But I am still a little bit worried that this problem could come back even with the "good" TP4056, because I highly doubt that same ICs from different manufacturers should behave so differently.

For those thinking that it might have been only one bad TP4056 - it was not. All C16581 that I had at home were having the same problem.

Has anyone ever experienced something like this? Does anybody know what could be causing such problem?

Comment: It is naive to think the same type number part from different manufacturers will be identical.  Nevertheless, show your pcb layout as this is a critical part of the circuit.

Comment: The charging circuit is in the upper right corner of the PCB. The layout in PDF also with the original KiCad files is here: [PDF layout](https://github.com/vedatori/TrackJet/blob/main/Hardware/Sergej_H00/PCB_layout.pdf); I did not mean that they would be identical. I just thought, that they would be functioning.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**
Low quality error prone clone ICs have polluted the market.

**Long answer:**
This is a surprisingly well know issue, but the info is scattered. And the prices are low so people are still buying them, as such these unfunctional chips are still flooding the market.

**Known problems**

- IC gets destroyed when used with a switch. - [Reference](https://www.reddit.com/r/batteries/comments/a80lbr/tp4056_destroyed/ecnnalz?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)
- Charging problems (see the comments section) - [Reference](http://jimlaurwilliams.org/wordpress/?p=4731)
- Wrongly placed resistors (for the module version) - [Reference](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/tp4056-protection-board-manufacture-error.149502/)
- Doesn't stop charging - [Reference](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/223366/tp4056-lithium-charger-module-issue)

**Clone vs Original**

[image]

PS:
Stay away from these ICs! I've read people trashing hundreds for their unreliability.

Comment: I will look for the desoldered ICs when I'm home and check how their marking looks.

Comment: Did you get a chance to compare these ICs?